# Internal points of $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

So, I have been taught that the empty set $\emptyset$ is both open and closed (if we can add "vacuously" it would be better).

$\emptyset$ is open because it contains all its internal points. But $\emptyset$ doesn't have any internal point, hence "vacuously" it contains them all, hence it's open.

Then I ask: why isn't $\mathbb{N}$ vacuously open too? I mean every point of $\mathbb{N}$ is both a boundary point and an isolated point.\
$\mathbb{N}$ has no internal point, hence... it contains them all, vacuously.

Where is the wrongness of my reasoning?

Comment: In what underlying space?  $\Bbb N$ *is* open in $\Bbb N$, but it's not open in $\Bbb R$ (assuming in both cases the usual topology).  A more accurate description of an open set is a set in which all of its points are internal points, rather than a set that contains all of its internal points.  The empty set satisfies that definition vacuously because, having no points, all of its points are necessarily internal.  But if you're looking at $\Bbb N \subseteq \Bbb R$, it's easy to see that $\Bbb N$ has points that aren't internal points.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Sorry, I'm in the standard Euclidean Topology

Comment: @RobertShore In $\mathbb{R}$. I cannot figure why, and it's an obvious trivial thing that I am missing... $\mathbb{N}$ has no internal points, after all. Why cannot I say it contains them all?

Comment: @RobertShore Oh, mayb I got it...

Comment: You can, but that doesn't describe an open set.  A set is open if every single one of its points is an internal point.  That's different (and stronger) than merely saying that it contains all of its internal points.  In fact, *every* set contains all of its internal points.

Comment: @RobertShore Ok, I think the confusion was due to the definition. I find it really different to say "a set that contains all its internal points" and "a set whose points are all internal points". In the second case it's "trivial" to understand why. In the firts case not. So is the second definition the correct one?

Comment: @RobertShore Got it!! Thanks!

Comment: You ask: "Where is the wrongness of my reasoning?" In the back of your mind, you assume on $\Bbb N$ the *trace topology* inherited from $\Bbb R$. Your question is mentioning isolated points and boundary points, which makes only sens if you assume a given topology. The only way to go without that is the empty set (not much choice on the topology).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is a misunderstanding of the definition.

You were claiming an open set is one that contains all of its internal points. However, **every** set satisfies this condition, since an internal point of a set lies in that set itself; notationally, $\operatorname{int}(A) \subseteq A$.

The correct definition is that a set is open if **every** point in the set is an internal point, i.e. $\operatorname{int}(A) = A$. This is a less trivial observation.

To see why $\mathbb{N}$ does not satisfy this criterion (as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ under the usual metric), let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and consider the ball $(n - \varepsilon, n + \varepsilon)$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$. This ball is never contained in $\mathbb{N}$, so $n$ is not an internal point. Hence, $\mathbb{N} \not \subseteq \operatorname{int}(\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: Thank you for this. Can I say that $\mathbb{N}$ is closed because it contains all its limit points (and since it has none, it satisfies vacuously the definition of closed set)?

Comment: That would be correct, yes.

Answer (score 1):

One shade of misunderstanding looks like you are assuming the *set* $\mathbb N$ to have a unique, unbending topology.

This is not true.

The most common, unmentioned topology on $\mathbb N$ is the one inherited as trace topology from $\mathbb R$, but that is not the only way possible. You could have a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space or the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_topology, or anything in between.

***Any set*** with more than one point can have more than one kind of topology.